# Effective video stream compression in C#

Tags: c#, video-streaming, audio-streaming, h.263

I am looking for a effective way to compress a real time video stream. In my project, the streaming seems important because my system will send and receive both the audio and video streams at the same time. I am considering using H261 or H263. How can I achieve such compression ratio using C#?

PS I found something called H323Plus, but I do not know how to call this library because it is written in C++.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do real-time streaming over UDP with both audio and video stream you can use the DirectShow API (if you're targeting Windows).

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375454(v=vs.85).aspx

You will find a .NET wrapper for DirectShow here

> http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/

You will also find more samples on codeproject.com, most of them use this wrapper

> http://www.codeproject.com/kb/audio-video/#DirectShow

If you plan on targeting Windows 7 and newer only, then you will want to use Windows Media Foundation API

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694197(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you. I would like to ask if DirectShow supports Win7? It seems that the samples of DirectShow on web are more abundant than that of WMF.

Comment: Looks like you will be safe to use DirectShow on Windows 7 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390976(v=vs.85).aspx